# Is my proof correct that there are uncountably many sets of positive integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers. Prove that $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is uncountable.

**Proof:** Suppose that $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is countable then $2^{\mathbb{N}}=\{A_1, A_2, A_3,\dots\}$. We have to construct the set $B$ which does not lie in $2^{\mathbb{N}}$. If $k\in A_k$ then $k\notin B$ and if $k\notin A_k$ then $k\in B$. Thus $B=\{i\in \mathbb{N}:i\notin A_i\}$. Note that $B$ is not empty since of one the $A_n$'s is empty. But $B$ is subset of $\mathbb{N}$ then $B=A_j$. But it's a contradiction since if $j\in A_j$ then $j\notin B$ and $j\notin A_j$ then $j\in B$ $\blacksquare$

Just now I am going to prove rigorously that if $S$ is countable then $2^S$ is uncountable.

**Proof:** Since $S$ is countable then exists bijective function $A: \mathbb{N} \to S$ letting $A(n)=A_n$. The natural corresponding between $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $2^S$ is defined by $\varphi: 2^{\mathbb{N}}\to 2^S$ and $$\varphi(n_1,\dots, n_k)=(A_{n_1},\dots, A_{n_k}),$$ $$\varphi(n_1,\dots, n_k, \dots)=(A_{n_1},\dots, A_{n_k},\dots).$$
It's easy to check that this function is bijection. We showed that $2^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable then $2^S$ is also uncountable.

Sorry if this topic is repeated but I would like to know are my proofs right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good! A couple comments:

- You should start by defining $B$ explicitly. That is, "Let $B=\{i\in\mathbb{N}: i\not\in A_i\}$" rather than "... Thus $B=\{i\in\mathbb{N}: i\not\in A_i\}.$" (Otherwise it sounds like $B$ has already been defined earlier.)
- Although it's true that $B\not=\emptyset$, this isn't relevant: you know $B\not=A_j$ for any $j$, without needing to prove that $B$ is nonempty.
- Some authors (such as I) use "countable" to include "finite" - under this usage, your second claim isn't true. Obviously this isn't a comment about your proof, just a statement of clarification (mostly, to forestall confusion in case you see statements e.g. on this site which allow countable to mean finite).
- Also, you don't need to define $\varphi$ by cases: just say $\varphi(X)=\{A(x): x\in X\}$.

Comment: Very nice remarks! Thanks a lot! But one moment about second point. What about if $B$ and $A_j$ are empty? Is it possible?

Comment: @RFZ Suppose $A_j$ is empty. Can you find an element of $B$? EDIT: To rephrase: suppose *all you know* is that $A_j$ is empty. What's something you *know* is in $B$?

Comment: In this case $j$ lies in $B$

Comment: @RFZ Bingo. Note that we didn't need the assumption $A_j=\emptyset$, merely $j\not\in A_j$, to conclude this. So really, the proof that $B\not=A_j$ for any $j$ is basically what you've already written: if $j\in A_j$, then $j\not\in B$, so $B\not=A_j$; and if $j\not\in A_j$, then $j\in B$, so $B\not=A_j$. Nowhere do I need to talk about whether $B$ is empty.